# How can I get the user's country from Sitecore Geolocation information?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, ip-geolocation

I have a Sitecore solution built using Sitecore 7.5.  We have also purchased the Sitecore IP Geolocation Service from the Sitecore App Center.  Now, once I have all of that running, how can I access the current user's country in code?  I can't seem to find any documentation that shows me how to get at any of the Geolocation information.

Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you have Analytics enabled. Try this:

```cs
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.GeoData.Country
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Where did you find it? Is there more documentation available somewhere?

Comment: @Dmytro 
does this initiate before Session loading ? 
Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.GeoData

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is now the correct way to do it:

```
Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.LookupManager.GetInformationByIp(string ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple form:

```
Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.MaxMindProvider maxMindProvider = new Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.MaxMindProvider();
Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.WhoIsInformation geoIpInformation = maxMindProvider.GetInformationByIp(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
string country = geoIpInformation.Country;
```

With caching:

```
System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress = null;

if (System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"], out ipAddress))
{
    Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.GeoIpOptions geoIpOptions = new Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.GeoIpOptions();
    geoIpOptions.Ip = ipAddress;
    geoIpOptions.MillisecondsTimeout = 1000;

    Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.GeoIpResult geoIpResult = Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.GeoIpManager.GetGeoIpData(geoIpOptions);

    if (geoIpResult != null)
    {
        string country = geoIpResult.GeoIpData.Country;
    }
}
```

Source: http://wiki.evident.nl/Sitecore%20MaxMind%20GeoIP%20api%20and%20cachinig.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: This is for the old (MaxMind-based) geo IP stuff. It's different for the new one.

Answer (score 0):

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/80/ip_geolocation/setting_up_sitecore_ip_geolocation you can try it as well for sitecore 8 web sites

Comment: This just includes installation instructions, not how to use it once installed.